# Git marging to branch and back to master

Tags: git, git-branch

I worked on a major refactoring of a big project. This refactoring was done on a dedicated branch, and is now finished.
During that time development on master continued. Now I'd like to merge all the fresh changes into branch, apply the refactoring to new code as well, test everything and push back to master.

Can anyone provide the steppes how to do it? I tried to do `git rebase master`, but it seems to overwrite all the changes on the branch, without asking me about merging conflicts.

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to checkout to the branch you want to merge to, and then do `git merge {name of the branch with changes}`

Read more on this site to learn how to undo a merge: http://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html